# my custom theme

Tags: android

Can i take this styles and make a theme with it in themes.XML and apply it to most of my activitys

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
    <style name="biglayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/pt5</item>
</style>
<style name="radiotiltebar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">44dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tilte2</item>

</style>
<style name="radiorelativelayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>

</style>
<style name="btn1">
    <item name="android:layout_width">106dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:drawableBottom">@drawable/note</item>



</style>
<style name="btn2">
    <item name="android:layout_width">108dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:drawableBottom">@drawable/key_icon</item>
</style>
<style name="btn3">
    <item name="android:layout_width">106dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_toLeftOf">@+id/button1</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:drawableBottom">@drawable/info</item>
</style>
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  style="@style/biglayout">

<RadioGroup
  android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
  style="@style/radiotiltebar">
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
  style="@style/radiorelativelayout" >
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  style="@style/btn1"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button2"
  style="@style/btn2" />
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button3"
  style="@style/btn3"/>"
</RelativeLayout>
</RadioGroup>
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
   style="@style/modelrelativelayout">
</RelativeLayout>
```

this style is my custom title bar. Which looks like this 
http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/3479/26906044.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a theme for the application all your buttons will look the same. The theme is applied to all your activities. For more details on how to do that see my answer here:
[Custom Views in the application (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017765/custom-views-in-the-application-android/10017892#10017892)